# Como cargar datos de un .txt en un arreglo en c++

Tags: c++, array, subida-de-archivos

en mi proyecto tengo una clase llamada clientes con 6 parametros, esta genera un arreglo donde quiero completar los datos de cada fila con un archivo .txt, los parametros son atributos y estan separados en el archivo por comas, entonces cada vez que encuentra una coma el programa deberia correrse un lugar en la columna para seguir cargando en el parametro del lado

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: No se entiende, las clases no tienen parámetros. Ayudaría algún(os) ejemplo(s).

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?™